# N- dimensional hypercube graph problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I have this problem:

Prove that the n-dimensional hypercube is a bipartite graph for every n bigger or equal to 2.

All help is welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by "dual graph"? This term is usually used with respect to a plane graph, and the $n$-dimensional hypercube graph is not planar for $n>3$.

Comment: Sorry in my language it's different it's actually bipartite graph.
I will edit it in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find chromatic number of the hypercube $Q_n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227681/how-to-find-chromatic-number-of-the-hypercube-q-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypercube's vertices are bitstrings of length $n.$ An edge correspond to flipping one bit. What can you say about the parity of the number of $1$ bits?

Comment: So with your hint my idea is: every vertex gives 0 or 1 by modulus 2. Also if lets say the dimension of a vertex is an odd number then all his neighbors are even numbers , so i can partition the set in to: $V1=\left \{ v1 \epsilon  V\mid v1=1(mod 2)\right \}$ 
and $ V2=\left \{ v2 \epsilon  V\mid v2=0(mod 2)\right \} $ which will give me the partitioning to show that it's bipartite.I don't know if that is all i have to write , so please tell me if there is anything else.

Comment: I have no idea what you have to write, but you seem to have the right idea.

Comment: Well i meant is this all there is to the solution or is there something more.